# Drainage problems and replacing existing grass

Tags: grass, drainage, clay

We have a lot of standing water after rain.  Also our grass is "mushy" long after the rain has past.  What is the best drainage and how do I prep my soil for new grass?

[image: the area]

Standing water:

[image: standing water]

Comment: I live in the Pacific Northwest.

Comment: Is there an area nearby that's lower? You could try to get all the water to one area then establish a rain garden.

Comment: This is an interesting question but more pictures and some idea of the dimensions in feet or meters would help

Comment: If you could look in your mortgage paperwork to find the AS BUILT that would should give elevations, under ground utilities, lot dimensions and codes that you can find that rule your piece of property.  If I had 3 elevations at least just relative heights, I could draw a contoured map with some ideas for drainage, ON SITE.  More information, measurements, pictures, please....Rain gardens are the rage in the PNW, I know but I no likey mosquitoes.

Comment: I hate to say this, sounds so lame, but I TAUGHT Grading and Drainage in the Landscape Architecture Program.  Helped my design abilities to see in 3D and sorry, drainage is numero uno importante for any home...building.  Should have been taken care of before your home was built.  I also built homes...yadayadayada...PNW.

Comment: @stormy.  I just went through all of the paperwork recieved when we purchased this house.  We are original owners.  I didn't find anything that said AS BUILT.  There were some papers with "county surveyor's copy" writtten on them.  I took a picture but not sure how to attach a photo.  control G isn't working.

Comment: Is it a 'treasure map made by pirates'?  looking document.  Sigh.  Does it have dimensions that make sense to you?  If not then I suggest getting a tape measure and a buddy and make measurements of everything.  There are wonderful measuring wheels made for home owners that you run along the ground and is accurate for measurements, lots easier, but a small piece of property is easy just with a good tape measure works.  Doesn't have to be perfect but the act of drawing up the base map of your property will connect you to your property quite intimately, quickly.  Better designing of YOUR space.

Comment: Wait, you are original owners?  Did you have this home custom built or was it a speculation home you were able to have some input?  Contact your Buildings and Code department where your home is on file.  See what they have filed on your home.  You should be able to do this via puter...

Comment: More pictures, this drainage can be easily fixed...perhaps with just a 'dry well'.  Ugh.  How long have you lived with this property?  While you are at it, get that contractor's name and information.  Where do you live?  Drainage like that is a MISTAKE by the contractor.  I worked in Washington State, and the law was; 12 years warranty unless specifically addressed and initialed in the contract.  Drainage like that tells me there is more wrong than mucky soil.  Do you have a basement?  Any water problems in your architecture?  Mold?...Truly, just gotta ask these questions.

Comment: @stormy.  We are original owners built in 1996 spec home.  I guess the neighbors across the cul-de-sac from us have it even worse.  Yes a basement but they put a sump pump there.  It is an unfinished basement and our funace and hot water are down there.  No mold.  We are Oregon.  We are leaning towards a flow well.  Just not sure who to trust to put it in.  (Do they reallly understand grading)  probably need a couple french drains leading to the flow well. Would you tie into down spout drainage system?

Comment: Whoa. Well, I am right here in Oregon, too.  I haven't looked into the Oregon RCWs about contractual warranties.  Interesting.  Washington has 12 years for discovery and correcting for any contractor unless they stipulated in a signed contract that their company only offered a one year warranty 'In Lieu of the Washington State RCW....blah blah blah'.  Be interesting to know what your options might be, especially with a neighbor splitting the costs.  Is a Flow Well perhaps the same thing as a Dry Well?  As long as you don't tie into the foundation drain, that would be fine. (Send a sketch?)

Comment: A flow well appears to be the same thing as what I call a dry well.  Easy, very inexpensive and a great bandaid for bad drainage!  From your pictures you might need two or three; 6'X6'X3' in depth holes, use the soil for plant beds, install landscape fabric, then fill with drain rock (rounded rock, 1 1 1/2" cobble), cover the rock with landscape fabric again then top with crushed gravel or bark?  Not for plants or lawn.  Have your 'herringbone' french drains lead right into this well.  This is kinda the only fix left to those who got stuck with bad grading and drainage. Luckily it works well.

Comment: French drains only need to be 6" in width and you most certainly can grow lawn and plants around them.  Easy to install in your established landscape.  The 'French Drain' comes in some vertical piping held together by a landscape fabric mesh, maybe 10" thick, 4" wide.

Comment: Thanks I think our plans are to do exactly what you are recommending.  Now just to find the right company to hire.  We want it done "right".